# Ordered dictionary output in python

Tags: python, dictionary, output

I have a following dictionary:

```
{'key1': 'list1', 'key2': 'list2', and so on}
```

I want to print it, and output it into a csv file in the following order:

```
key1 list1_element_1
key1 list1_element_2
key1 list1_element_n
key2 list2_element_1
key2 list2_element_n
```

How do I do that? This may(quite possibly) be an elementary question, however I could not find the answer. Thanks.

Comment: A dictionary cannot look like that, you can only store one value for `key1`. Are your values lists, tuples maybe? Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Whoah, sorry. Values are indeed lists. So, for every key, there is a corresponding list of strings. Would it be possible to have the output I need from this structure?

Comment: What do you mean by "ordered"? What order do you need the result in? Dictionary keys are unordered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your values are lists/tuples you can do the following and that you are using [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

```
dictionary = {'key1': ['value1', 'value2', 'value3'], 'key2': ['value1', 'value2']}

for key, values in dictionary.items():
   for value in values:
       print '{} {}'.format(key, value)
```

If you are using a normal dict (i.e. not an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)) then you need to sort first:

```
dictionary = {'key1': ['value1', 'value2', 'value3'], 'key2': ['value1', 'value2']}

for key, values in sorted(dictionary.items()):
   for value in values:
       print '{} {}'.format(key, value)
```

The code above only prints the values as you had in your example output. You can write them to a csv file or do whatever you desire.

The output for the second example would be:

```
key1 value1
key1 value2
key1 value3
key2 value1
key2 value2
```

Comment: you are missing the fact that a single key has multiple values!

Comment: This will yield the keys in arbitrary order, as dicts are not ordered.

Comment: He said it's an "Ordered dictionary" (I assumed OrderedDict)

Comment: Hm, thats one way to read it. I read it like "how do I make it ordered"... Using a orderedDict wouldn't quite fit to the level of this question though.

Comment: Ah fair enough, I didn't read it that way but now that you say it, I'm reading it that way :D

Comment: @SamyArous, could you elaborate with an example? This would print it as expected.

Comment: @s16h according to the OP example, each value is printed on its own line. two values that have the same key will be rendered in two different lines while in your case, they would be printed in a single line as a tuple :)

Comment: The only order I need is that key n-1 goes before key n, I am not concerned with the order of values

Comment: @SamyArous, I may be having a bit of a special moment here/misunderstanding you, but when two values have the same key, they will be printed on separate lines in my code. Is that what you mean? Don't forget, with print ["A '\n' character is written at the end, unless the print statement ends with a comma."](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#print). I'll update the answer with the output.

Comment: @s16h Never mind, either you fixed your code on your own, or I'm the one who should go get some sleep :p

Answer (score 1):

There are two concepts related to your problem here.

1. How to store a multidictionary
2. How to store an ordered dictionary

For the first problem, you simply store a list of values for each key instead of one single value
For the second problem, you can use the [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects) from the [collections](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) library

```
import collections

def add_value(d, key, value):
    # get a list of values by key or set a default empty list
    lst = d.setdefault(key, list())
    lst.append(value)

def print_dict(d):
    for key, values in d.items():
        for single in values:
            print "{} {}".format(key, single)


d = collections.OrderedDict()
add_value(d, "key1", "value1")
add_value(d, "key1", "value2")
add_value(d, "key1", "valueN")
add_value(d, "key2", "value1")
add_value(d, "key2", "value2")
print_dict(d)
```

Comment: **Note:** The order of an `OrderedDict` is insertion order, not sorted order.  This means that the order you add the keys matters.  This is why Samy Arous does not declare the dictionary as a dict-literal.

Answer (score 0):

First, a key cannot have more than one value associated to it.

Assuming a single key/value pair, sample code would be

```
info = {
"key1":"xyz",
"key4":"anotherrandom",
"key2":"abaadfas",
"key3":"random"
      }
for key in sorted(info):
        print "key: {} and value: {}".format(key,info[key])
```

If you want to associate more than value to a key, you could use a list.

```
info = {
"key1": [1,2,3],
"key4": [1],
"key2": [5,7,8],
"key3": [0,11,7,8]

}
for key in sorted(info):
    print "key: {} and value: {}".format(key,info[key])
```